# If RAISERROR is as good as deprecated, how are you supposed to flush the PRINT buffer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, raiserror

`RAISERROR` is as good as deprecated. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) says

> New applications should use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`.

Yet, it is commonly used to [flush the PRINT buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql).

Suppose that I'm writing a long stored procedure and I want regular reports of what step it is on. If `RAISERROR` is out of the question, how should I `PRINT` from it?

Assume a relatively recent version of SQL Server. Let's say 2019.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### lots of things are deprecated

Which for Microsoft just means they're not actively being developed any further. None of that stuff ever really gets pulled from the product though.

But `RAISERROR` is not listed as deprecated anywhere.

It's not here:

- [SQL Server, Deprecated Features object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-deprecated-features-object?view=sql-server-ver16)

Except for this note:

[image: NUTS]

And it's not listed here, either:

```
SELECT
    pc.*
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters AS pc
WHERE object_name LIKE 'SQLServer:Deprecated Features%'
ORDER BY
    pc.instance_name;
```

You're not in any danger of not being able to use it. If you look at the list of things that *are* officially deprecated, nearly all of them are still in the product as of SQL Server 2022.

It's quite difficult for Microsoft to fully remove anything, even with years of notice, because of the amount of screaming that will happen if something suddenly stops working that had been working for 20+ years.

Comment: This is correct and helpful, but it avoids the question.

Comment: Well, the question is moot because there's no reason not to use RAISERROR.

Comment: @J.Mini What question does it avoid? There’s no direct replacement and it’s not deprecated. What else do you need?